# How do I make modulo and logical indexing work faster?

Tags: matlab, indexing

Consider the following command:

```
c(c>A | c<1) = mod(c(c>A | c<1),A);
```

where `c` is a column vector, and `A` is a scalar.

**In short**: Is there any way to make this work faster?

Explanation:

`c(i)` represents a column number in an `A`-by-`A` matrix. However, it may have values greater than `A` or smaller than 1, and this command should fix it in a sort of 'PAC-MAN' way. If `c(i)` is greater than `A` then when you reach `A` start counting back from 1, if you reach `A` again start again from 1, and so forth, until you count to the value of `c(i)`. This should work in the same way for `c(i)<1`, so the counting will be reversed.

Examples:

- If `A = 10` and `c(i) = 17`, then `c(i)` after this command
  should be 7.
- If `A = 10` and `c(i) = -8`, then `c(i)` after this command
  should be 2.
- If `A = 10` and `c(i) = 213`, then `c(i)` after this command
  should be 3.

The motivation: This command is a part of a simulation model I have, and currently it is the slowest part in it. This specific row is called millions(!) of times in each realization of the model, and there are a lot, so any improvement will be helpful. BTW, the typical size of `c` is about 10K-by-1.

p.s.: if you have a better suggestion for the title, I'll be happy to change it, I couldn't find a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to actually do any logical indexing here because any values excluded by `c > A | c < 1` will not be touched by `mod` and it will likely be faster to just pass *everything* to `mod` rather than doing comparisons and indexing to determine which values to pass to `mod`.

```
c = [17 -8 213, 7];

c = mod(c, A);
%   7   2   3   7
```

In general though, for other functions in which you need logical indexing on the input and output of a function, you'll want to store the logical array in a temporary variable rather than computing it twice:

```
touse = c < 1 | c > A;
c(touse) = mod(c(touse), A);
```

Here is a quick little benchmark showing the relative performance of each method:

```
function timemod()

    sizes = round(linspace(100, 100000, 10));

    [times1, times2, times3] = deal(zeros(numel(sizes), 1));

    A = 10;

    for k = 1:numel(sizes)

        data = round(rand(sizes(k), 1) * A * 100);
        times1(k) = timeit(@()indexing(data, A));

        data = round(rand(sizes(k), 1) * A * 100);
        times2(k) = timeit(@()indexing_temp(data, A));

        data = round(rand(sizes(k), 1) * A * 100);
        times3(k) = timeit(@()mod(data, A));
    end

    figure
    plot(sizes, 1000 * cat(2, times1, times2, times3))
    legend({'Indexing', 'Indexing w/ temp', 'No Indexing'})

    xlabel('Number of Elements')
    ylabel('Execution Time (ms)')

    fprintf('Indexing:              %0.2f ms\n', mean(times1 * 1000))
    fprintf('Indexing with temp:    %0.2f ms\n', mean(times2 * 1000))
    fprintf('No Indexing or temp:   %0.2f ms\n', mean(times3 * 1000))
end

function data = indexing(data, A)
    data(data > A | data < 1) = mod(data(data > A | data < 1), A);
end

function data = indexing_temp(data, A)
    inds = data > A | data < 1;
    data(inds) = mod(data(inds), A);
end
```

[image]

Comment: This was brilliant! Thanks a lot. I can't believe I missed this option... now I'll finish my PhD a little bit sooner ;)

Comment: Can you add a forth option to the answer where `c1 = mod(c,A)` (assignment to another variable)? In my machine is the fastest.

Comment: @EBH Did you actually test this with the benchmark code? There shouldn't be a real difference compared to `c = mod(c, A)` when you profile it correctly (with `timeit`)

Comment: @EBH timeit is more accurate

Comment: @EBH [Measure Performance of Your Program](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/measure-performance-of-your-program.html)

Comment: @EBH I could add that but I don't think it adds much since we wouldn't expect it to be any different and it isn't.